# Assign a char pointer the value of another char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have two char pointers:

```
char *temp;
char *saveAlias;
```

I want to assign `saveAlias` with whatever is stored in `temp`; `saveAlias` is currently empty while `temp` has a string of an unknown size saved from user input.
Note that I don't want `saveAlias` to point to where `temp` points; I want the content of `temp` and assign (get pointed) it to `saveAlias`.

I have attempted using `strcat` and `strcpy` but to no avail.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble distinguishing between pointers and the objects to which they point, at least in your wording. You can assign `saveAlias` to point to the same object that `temp` does via the assignment operator (`=`).  If, on the other hand, you want to copy the data to which `temp` points then you first need `saveAlias` to point to a modifiable object of sufficient size, which is by no means automatic.  It's unclear what, exactly, you want to do and what you are trying; for more specific help we need you to present demonstrative code, more than just declarations.

Comment: Correction: you have two *Uninitialized* character pointers that current hold (e.g. point to) indeterminate addresses as their values. You can do little with them until they provide to a valid memory address.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `temp` variable points to a character string that is suitably `nul`-terminated (as strings in C *should* be), then you can just use the [`strdup()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) to make a copy of it and store a pointer to that in `saveAlias`. This function will **dup**licate the given **str**ing into newly-allocated memory; that memory should be released, using the `free` function, when no longer needed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* temp = "source string";
    char* saveAlias = strdup(temp);
    printf("Temp is <%s> (at %p).\n", temp, (void*)temp);
    printf("Alias is <%s> (at %p).\n", saveAlias, (void*)saveAlias);
    free(saveAlias);
    return 0;
}
```

The `strdup` function effectively combines `malloc` and `strcpy` into a single function call, with the call shown above being the equivalent of:

```c
    char* saveAlias = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
    strcpy(saveAlias, temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate memory for a copy of the string currently pointed to by `temp`, use `strdup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[128];
    char *temp;
    char *saveAlias = NULL;

    if ((temp = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) != NULL) {
        saveAlias = strdup(temp);
        if (saveAlias == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed\n");
        } else {
            printf("saveAlias: %s\n", saveAlias);
        }
    }
    free(saveAlias);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically point the saveAlias to temp; Thus you would have:

`saveAlias = temp;`

As noted by Chris. This will make one pointer point to another.
Correcting my answer. I suggest you define de size of saveAlias with malloc, and then use the memcpy function. You will have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  
int main(){    
   char *temp = "your_char";

   //with malloc you make sure saveAlias will have the same size as temp
   //and then we add one for the NULL terminator
   char *saveAlias = (char*) malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
            
   //then just                                                                                                                                            
   strcpy(saveAlias, temp);
 
   printf("%s\n", temp);
   printf("%s", saveAlias);
   return 0;            
}
```

Thank you `chqrlie` for the explanation also. I was mistaken about the memcpy.

Comment: This does not point saveAlias at temp -- it points saveAlias at whatever temp is pointing at.  An important difference.

Comment: @ChrisDodd thank you for noticing that. I've updated the answer with the properly solution.

Comment: you used `sizeof(temp)` in the memcpy. Why don't you try changing the string from `"your_char"` to `"your_char_test_long"` and see what happens

Comment: Why does the overflow happens would you mind explain? @mr.loop I have tested and memcpy copy the value and override it in the other pointer.

Comment: Incorrect allocation size, you must add one for the null terminator: `char *saveAlias = (char*) malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);` and ivalid size for `memcpy`, just use `strcpy(saveAlias, temp);` or better use `strdup()`: `char *saveAlias = strdup(temp);`

Comment: Whould yo mind explain also why if I pass the address of temp instead of temp itself in the sizeof function it works? `sizeof(&temp)` inside memcpy.

Comment: Forget what I said. It didn't. I forgot to recompile. I think you can post yours as a solution to this question then. =)

Comment: @chqrlie nothing changes if we use `strlen(temp)` or `strlen(temp)+1`. what matters is sizeof(temp) is a contant value at 8 bytes and hence memcpy wasn't copying more than that.

Comment: @mr.loop: there were indeed 2 distinct errors.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, you're right, we need to use `strlen(temp)+1` to allocate space for null terminator because strlen in this case wouldn't account for that